# Merging one SQL database into another

Tags: bash, mariadb, google-cloud-sql

Currently in my CI I'm completely wiping production db with development db. That was fine for testing but I'm coming to a stage where I need to start merging instead of completely wiping.

Right now the command I'm using to wipe and write is as follows:

```
mysqldump -u "$DB_USERNAME" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" -h "$DB_HOST" "development" > dump.sql
mysql -u "$DB_USERNAME" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" -h "$DB_HOST" "production" < dump.sql
```

I tried the following for merging:

```
mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info -u "$DB_USERNAME" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" -h "$DB_HOST" "development" > dump.sql
```

Which I thought would do the trick but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 23: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Any ideas where I'm falling short?

Comment: There will always be headaches with that approach because of the keys, whether primary or unique. What we typically do is the other way around: dump a copy the production DB to use _as_ the dev database.

Comment: @PaulT.: where you say "a copy the production DB", you mean "a copy *of* the production DB", I suppose.

Comment: @PierreFrançois ... Yes, that is correct, missed that `of`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the mysqldump will probably work:

```
 --insert-ignore
```

The error message implies that you already have a row with primary key id=1 and are trying to add it again.

Caveat:  If you have *modified* that row, this technique will not achieve the "merge" goal.  Please specify the "merge" more thoroughly.